# getimagesize() error: “failed to open stream: No such file or directory”(could not find any matching solution to my issue)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to make a webpage for adding profile picture to registered user profile.

I'm using PHP and MySql(phpMyadmin) as back-end(xampp server).

I'm currently working from localhost for development purpose.

Now the problem is every time I choose a file to upload and click on upload button, the following error message showing on screen :
"Warning: getimagesize(file1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Digital Portfolio\upload.php on line 38
File is not an image.Sorry, your file was not uploaded."

What is wrong with my code, if any? Can I have a solution of the problem?

The HTML code(within the same php file to execute file upload) for uploading profile image is as follows:

```
    <div class="profile-img-upload"> 
       <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label style="color:white;">Select Image File to Upload : </label>
            <input type="file" name="file" class="upload-choice">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
       </form>
    </div>
```

The PHP code to execute the post command of the above form is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();

$insert_error = false;
if($_SESSION["status"]=="loggedin") {
    // Include the database configuration file
    include 'db_connect.php';
    $con = OpenCon();
    $unam = $_SESSION["user_name"];
    
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $target_dir = "pics&icons/uploads/";
        $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $target_file = $target_dir . $fileName;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        
        $check = getimagesize($fileName);
        
        if($check != false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        
        // Check file size
        elseif ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 10000000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        
        // Allow certain file formats
        elseif($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: `basename` removes all path information from a file which is what you are doing. Instead you want to be looking at the unaltered `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`

Comment: Thank you very much brother....problem resolved with a bit different approach but a new problem arise when I tried to update my mysql database with image file path and date of upload in my 'user_account' table... it takes only '0' in 'file_path' column and no change in 'uploaded_on' column(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database; in this case I don't see anything that has to do with phpMyAdmin itself. In fact, the error message seems to be related to PHP directly, not even MySQL.